# Unable to check the user already exist or not in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android app to login the users by using Mobile number OTP verification from fire-base [This is how the database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxTFN.png)

This is the login activity where i am passing the value "mobile" to OTP typing activity( here LoginActivity.java)

```
 CardView card_view = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     String mobile = editTextMobile.getText().toString().trim();

        if(mobile.isEmpty() || mobile.length() < 10){
          editTextMobile.setError("Enter a valid mobile");
            editTextMobile.requestFocus();
               return;
             }

             if(mobile.length()>10)
        {
            editTextMobile.setError("Enter a valid mobile");
            editTextMobile.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

       Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, VerifyPhoneActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
              startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

This is where user will enter the OTP (VerifyPhoneActivity.java). If the OTP is correct and if the mobile number is not exist in database already then user can go to sigh up up activity

```
public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//These are the objects needed
//It is the verification id that will be sent to the user
private String mVerificationId;
 DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//The edittext to input the code
private EditText editTextCode;

//firebase auth object
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String   code;
String mobile;
String codesent;
public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    sendVerificationCode();

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            verifySignInCode();                
        }
    });
}


private void verifySignInCode()
    {

        final EditText fd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        String value= fd.getText().toString();

        final EditText sd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        String value1= sd.getText().toString();
        // int finalValue1=Integer.parseInt(value1);

        EditText td = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        String value2= td.getText().toString();

        EditText fod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4);
        String value3= fod.getText().toString();

        EditText fid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et5);
        String value4= fid.getText().toString();

        EditText sid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et6);
        String value5= sid.getText().toString();

        code = value + value1+value2+value3+value4+value5;

        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codesent, code);

        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                       DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        FirebaseUser userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        final String uid = userid.getUid();
                        ref.child("Users");
                        ref.child(mobile).child(uid);

                        Log.d("myTag", mobile);
                        Log.d("myTag", uid);

                        DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

                        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                } else {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, Signup.class);

                                    intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                   // Intent myIntent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, Signup.class);
                                   // startActivity(myIntent);

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "account not exist",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login faild",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                       // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OTP was wrong",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks=new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "verification completed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sending faild"+e,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
       // super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        codesent=s;
    }
};

private void sendVerificationCode() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mobile = intent.getStringExtra("mobile");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mobile,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String phonenumber= "+91"+mobile;
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phonenumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}
}
```

And at last this is Signup.java

```
public class Signup extends Activity {

String name;
String address;
String pincode;
String city;
String mobile;
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
FirebaseUser userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

final String uid = userid.getUid();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mobile = intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
    findViewById(R.id.signupbutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mobile,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("myTag", mobile);
            Log.d("myTag", uid);

            EditText nameedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametextview);
             name= nameedittext.getText().toString();

            EditText addressedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addresstextview);
            address= addressedittext.getText().toString();

            EditText pincodeedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.picodetextview);
            pincode= pincodeedittext.getText().toString();

            EditText cityedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.citytextview);
            city= cityedittext.getText().toString();

            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

              ref = ref.child("Users");

            ref = ref.child(mobile).child(uid);

              Map<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();

             userData.put("Name", name);
             userData.put("Address", address);
             userData.put("Pin", pincode);
             userData.put("City", city);

              ref.setValue(userData);
        }
    });
}
}
```

- The problem is if the first user is signed up with his phone number then the second user is unable to sign up in app saying account already exist

I think it is the problem of checking for the data already exist or not in verifyphoneactivity.java please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the code shown in your question, the following things stand out:

1. The `Signup` activity is already logged in when creating a new user? This means that when you are going through the signup process, the previous userId is used to signup the user, not that of the new user.
2. Your code uses both `"Users"` and `"users"` - Firebase is case sensitive.
3. Your phone number form handling could be more intelligent and support area codes (e.g. +91xxxxxxxxx). This will be beneficial for expansion to new regions rather than just checking for 10 numbers.
4. The code above doesn't handle auto-retrieval of the verification code. ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks))

### Side notes

**Note 1:** Consider using a phone number to user ID index/map. You'll refer to a user by their userId more often than their phone number and it will save you constantly passing it through your app.

```
{
  "PhoneNumbers": {
    "1234555888": "userId1",
    "1234555888": "userId2",
  },
  "Users": {
    "userId1": {
      ...
    },
    "userId2": {
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

**Note 2:** Pin codes are stored insecurely and should be hashed/fed to a calculation rather than stored in plain text.